# Why does sw command not save to variable?

Tags: assembly, mips

Okay, let me start by saying I'm new to assembly. I'm trying to make a program to add together two integers, and output the result. That works when I do it this way:

```
    .data
A:  .word 0 #declare two integers with initial value 3 and the sum variable
B:  .word 0
S:  .word 0 #getting the string in advance
line:   .asciiz "The sum of A and B (A + B) is "
    .text
main:
    li  $v0, 5  #load input syscall code
    syscall     #call for operating system to perform operation
    sw  $v0, A  #value read from keyboard returned in register $v0
    li  $v0, 5  #load input syscall code
    syscall     #call for operating system to perform operation
    sw  $v0, B  #value read from keyboard returned in register $v0
    la  $a0,A
    lw  $t0, ($a0)
    la  $a0,B
    lw  $t2, ($a0)
    add     $t1,$t2,$t0 #adding the numbers
    
    sw  $t1,S #--------line in question(b)
    
    li  $v0, 4  #load output string syscall
    la  $a0, line #load address of string to be printed into $a0
    syscall
    li  $v0, 1
    la  $a0, ($t1) #----------line in question (a)
    syscall
```

However, I'm supposed to output the variable not just output $t1, but when I change line in question (a) to

```
la $a0, S
```

I get this

> 5
>
> 6
>
> The sum of A and B (A + B) is 268501000

I'm assuming line in question (b)
is the problem because it doesnt seem to be saving the information to B. I tried to fix this on my own, but I'm stumped.

Comment: `la` loads the address, `lw` would load the value. Using `lw $a0, S` would do what you want. There's nothing wrong with `sw` Also remember the exit syscall in the end.

Comment: the `syscall` may change values of `t0 - t7` registers, so you shouldn't use it again after displaying the prompt. And to copy value between two registers you can use pseudo instruction `mov $rt, $rs` (`rt = rs`), I'm not even sure what `la  $a0, ($t1)` really does, does it compile? Or was it `lw  $a0, ($t1)`? Then you are using value of sum (or whatever value `syscall` leaves in `t1`) as memory address, which is not your intent.

Comment: BTW, you should rather use debugger and instruction-stepping to verify values and complete CPU state, and memory content. Debug outputs are used only when no debugger is available, and they are much harder to use, requires already lot of asm experience and skill to use them effectively. Your source looks like MARS/SPIM environment family, so you **do have** debugger. Learn to use it early, and often.